# Move data to beginning of partition

Tags: dd

I'm going to move the data from a 2Tio drive to an SSD, whick is only 120Gio. The drive only has one partition and only contains like 16Gio. To make sure I get everything when transferring with ddrescue, I want to make sure all data is in the beginning of the partition. Any tools to do that?;)

Comment: Hi. Firstly, Tio/Gio seems to be confusing nomenclature. I would recommend using TB/GB. Second, it is the 2TB drive that only contains 16GB of data?

Comment: Yes, the 2TB drive only contains 16GB of data;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ddrescue` is involved, it suggests the source drive is not exactly in good health. In that case, you should not modify the source drive in any way before copying, as it might make the problem worse.

**Only if** the source disk is healthy, and the filesystem type on the source disk supports shrinking the filesystem, you could do that first.

The filesystem type is important here: for ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems, you could make sure the filesystem-to-be-shrunk is unmounted, and then run `resize2fs <partition device containing the filesystem> 20G` to shrink the size of the filesystem to 20 GiB. If the operation is not possible, the command will return an error without making any changes. If the operation completes successfully, it is guaranteed that all the data is within 20 GiB from the start of the partition in question. You could then adjust the size of the partition, preferably to 21 GiB or greater to avoid cutting off the tail end of the filesystem because of rounding errors. Once the filesystem has been successfully copied, you could then use `resize2fs` without the size parameter to automatically resize the filesystem to exactly match the partition's current size.

Other filesystem types have their own specific tools for size adjustment: `resize2fs` is specific to the ext2/ext3/ext4 family of filesystems only.

As far as I know, there currently isn't any production-grade tool to shrink XFS filesystems, neither online nor offline.

`ddrescue` will attempt to make an exact, one-to-one copy from the source to the destination: that is its job. If you run it to copy everything from the 2 TiB drive to a 120 GiB drive, you'll get an exact copy of the first 120 GiB or so of the source disk.

If the only thing that's done with the source disk after creating the filesystem on it was to transfer the 16 GiB of data into it, I would say there's usually a pretty good chance that all the data is fully contained within the first 120 GiB, but that depends on the filesystem type and the block allocation method it uses.

But if the filesystem used to contain 120 GiB+ of something else before the 16 GiB of data was copied to it, even if the other data was deleted later, the 16 GiB of current data might be located further than 120 GiB away from the beginning of the disk.

Comment: It's ext3, so a good solution is to use resize2fs;) thanks;)

Comment: Also, the drive is working ok; I just always use ddrescue;)

Comment: @JasonHunter if the drive is working and the filesystem intact, why not just use `cp`? Then, there would be no concern about how the filesystem is distributed on the source drive.

Comment: If partition is old ext3, time to change to ext4. Is this a bootable partition or just data? If bootable & you want to keep HDD, you have to change UUID in one or the other before rebooting as you cannot have duplicate UUIDs.  And then new install to ext4 & cp or rsync your /home & any other data & list of installed apps would probably better better option. Also if SSD will in future be used in newer UEFI system, better to also convert to gpt partitioning. But if BIOS, you need a tiny 1MB bios_grub partition for grub to reinstall correctly. And may want to allocate ESP for future also.